# Why does my code not show up with the font and positioning I chose? I refresh & it shows up for a sec

Tags: html, css, html-email, inline

I am creating my first personal web page but I am having issues with it showing correctly on chrome. What am I doing wrong with my inline html/css code?

When I open it from my laptop as the .html file it shows correctly with the font, image styling, etc that I want. Problem is when I open it as an email I send, it shows up without the font & without my image being on the right(as a circle). I don't know what else I can do to fix this issue. I am a beginner & if you have more knowledge I'd appreciate the help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

            <title>Cecilia Cevi</title>
            <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css 
     family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet">

    </head>



    <body
        style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; background- 
    color: #0B0C10; font-size:20px">


        <div class="left">
            <header>
                <h1
                    style="color:#66FCF1; font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-s 
    serif; background-color: #1F2833; border:1px solid white; width: 
    200px;">Cecila Cevi</h1>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <style>
                img {
                float: right;
                border-radius: 50%;
                }
            </style>
            <img class="profile-picture"
                src="https://i.lensdump.com/i/ilE9n0.jpg" alt="girl" width="400"
                float: " right " radius: "50%" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <main
                style="background-color: #1F2833;border: 1px solid black: width: 
    300px; max-width:1000px;">

                <h2 style="color: #66FCF1;">Biography</h2>
                <p style="color: #C5C6C7;">Information</p>
                <hr>

                    <h2 style="color: #66FCF1;">My Work</h2>
                    <p style="color: #C5C6C7;">In the</p>
                    <hr>
        </div>


        <div style="background-color: #45A29E; border: 1px solid white;">
            <h2 style="color: #C5C6C7;">Digital Projects</h2>
            <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="empty">
            </a>

        </div>
    </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code. Replace this line

```
<img class="profile-picture"
                src="https://i.lensdump.com/i/ilE9n0.jpg" alt="girl" width="400"
                float: " right " radius: " />
```

With this:

```
<img class="profile-picture" src="https://i.lensdump.com/i/ilE9n0.jpg" alt="girl" width="400" float="right" radius="" />
```

Comment: That mistake isn't actually in OPs code, just an editor messed it up there. The original content is `radius:"50%"` (see the first revision of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58466973/1)

Comment: I've re-added the missing information (restored the original version in that sense) from the tag. You were correct in spotting that mistake, but the issue isn't in OPs version, thus this answer won't help OP in finding the solution to their problem. If you agree, then you can either update your answer to fix the actual issue or delete it.

Comment: Yes may be editor mistake, but i found so i mentioned :) , i hope problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

One big lesson here is that email client rendering engines are way behind modern browser rendering engines. That includes the code base.
Floats, border radius, custom fonts and even max-widths won't work in certain email clients.

It's not as simple as just taking a web page and dropping it into an email service.

1. Custom fonts from services such as Google Fonts, will not work everywhere. Two major email clients they won't work are Outlook (of course) and Gmail. Yes, Gmail doesn't support their own font service for email. Stupid, right?
2. The alignment on your image needs to be achieved with the align attribute (align="right"), directly on the wrapping element. Floats will work in some clients but for the best support, it's best to stick with the native align attribute.
3. Divs can work in email, if you understand the quirks and know how to fix them in clients such as Outlook. If you're a beginner email coder, you're best sticking with tables. Old school, but trust me, they cause less headaches!
4. There is potential the HTML5 tags could have the same detrimental effect as divs, but I can't confirm that as I haven't used them a lot. 
   *** And I should note, detrimental in that they blow out widths. HTML5 tags and divs won't necessarily tear your email apart. They may just force your template to not adhere to the widths you've defined.

Unfortunately, there aren't any simple and easy fixes for your code.
You'll need to learn more about the different techniques required to achieve your design, or you could simplify your design to work for a basic email layout.

Here are some resources you can utilize to learn more about email:

- [New to email coding? Here’s where to start.](https://explore.reallygoodemails.com/new-to-email-coding-heres-where-to-start-2494422f0bd4)
- [Creating a Simple Responsive HTML Email](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978)
- [The Basics of Modern HTML Emails](https://blog.edmdesigner.com/the-basics-of-modern-html-emails/)

Comment: No worries, my pleasure :)